# How to implement async waiting loop with packaged_task in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading

Let us say, that we use `packaged_task` for implementing async work in a program.

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    std::packaged_task<int()> packagedTaskOne([]()
        {
            using namespace std::chrono_literals;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(4s);
            return 4;
        });

    std::future<int> futureResultOne = packagedTaskOne.get_future();
    std::thread tOne(std::move(packagedTaskOne));

    futureResultOne.wait();
    tOne.join();

    std::cout << "done\n";

    return 0;
}
```

I can barely imagine how to implement `waiting cursor` in C#, because I can use something like `while(!Task.Run(async () => await _service.GetValue()).IsCompleted)` and output some dots that show loading. I want the same with `packaged_task` but I do not understand how to fuse it with `while` loop because I do not get what a condition I should for checking is this thread completed. How to make the same loop in C++ with `packaged_task?`

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: The documentation of `wait_for` seems to have what you are looking for? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/wait_for

Comment: So you want to get a way to check if some thread has finished its work or not?

Comment: @asmmo yes!!! that is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use `futureResultOne.get();` to avoid blocking, the following is a way to check if your task has finished or not in the main (you can use an independent one of course) thread.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <condition_variable>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

std::condition_variable cv;
bool theThreadHasFinished;
std::mutex mut;
int main()
{
    std::packaged_task<int()> packagedTaskOne([]{
                                                  std::this_thread::sleep_for(4s);
                                                  return 4;
                                              });

    std::future<int> futureResultOne = packagedTaskOne.get_future();
    std::thread tOne([&]{packagedTaskOne();
        std::lock_guard lg{mut};
        theThreadHasFinished = true;
        cv.notify_all();});
    tOne.detach();
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{ mut };
    cv.wait(lock, [ ](){ return theThreadHasFinished; });
    std::cout << "done\n";

    return 0;
}
```

You can use a `while` loop ad `wait_for` but this consumes your resources